# Google Appscript, Fetch API XML and get child of child

Tags: xml, api, google-apps-script

I am a bit stuck on dealing with multi-level XML with Google App Script.

I am doing an API XML fetch with a UrlFetchApp.fetch() command. It's working. The XML format looks like below:

```
<CALENDAR>
    <CalendarManager>
       <Categories>
            <Category Id="1" AuthorId="1234">
                <Author Legacy="True"></Author>
                <Name></Name>
                <LastUpdated></LastUpdated>
            </Category>
            <Category Id="2" AuthorId="1234">
                <Author Legacy="True"></Author>
                <Name></Name>
                <LastUpdated></LastUpdated>
                <Subcategories>
                    <Subcategory Id="1" AuthorId="1324">
                        <Author Legacy="True"></Author>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <LastUpdated></LastUpdated>
                    </Subcategory>
                    <Subcategory Id="2" AuthorId="1234">
                        <Author Legacy="True"></Author>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <LastUpdated></LastUpdated>
                    </Subcategory>
            </Category>
        </Categories>
    </CalendarManager>
</CALENDAR>
```

Here's the main chunk of my code. Currently, I am able to grab the information from Category as you can see my in my snippet of my code below. My issue is every attempt I made to grab the subcategory if there is one that exists I am unable to assign the data to a variable.

```
// Get Category Information 
var rAndCTypes = root.getChild('CalendarManager').getChild('Categories').getChildren('Category');  
  for (var r = 0; r < rAndCTypes.length; r++) {
    var rAndC = rAndCTypes[r];
    var typeIdID =  rAndC.getAttribute('Id').getValue().replace(/['=Id]/g, "");
    var AuthorId =  rAndC.getAttribute('AuthorId').getValue().replace(/['=AuthorId]/g, "");
    var authorLegacy = rAndC.getContent(0).getValue();        
    var name = rAndC.getContent(1).getValue();
    var lastUpdated = rAndC.getContent(2).getValue();

  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have spent the entire day stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You should get the next child by using getContent(3)

In order to avoid null children, then use a conditional for subcategories before. Here's an example:

```
var rAndCTypes = root.getChild('CalendarManager').getChild('Categories').getChildren('Category');  
  for (var r = 0; r < rAndCTypes.length; r++) {
    var rAndC = rAndCTypes[r];
    var typeIdID =  rAndC.getAttribute('Id').getValue().replace(/['=Id]/g, "");
    var AuthorId =  rAndC.getAttribute('AuthorId').getValue().replace(/['=AuthorId]/g, "");
    var authorLegacy = rAndC.getContent(0).getValue();        
    var name = rAndC.getContent(1).getValue();
    var lastUpdated = rAndC.getContent(2).getValue();
    var subcategories = rAndC.getContent(3);

    if(subcategories) {
      subcategoriesChildren = subcategories.getChildren('Subcategory');
      for (var i = 0; i < subcategoriesChildren.length; i++) {
        var sub = subcategoriesChildren[i];
        var subTypeIdID =  sub.getAttribute('Id').getValue().replace(/['=Id]/g, "");
        var subAuthorId =  sub.getAttribute('AuthorId').getValue().replace(/['=AuthorId]/g, "");
        var subAuthorLegacy = sub.getContent(0).getValue();        
        var subName = sub.getContent(1).getValue();
        var subLastUpdated = sub.getContent(2).getValue();
      }
    }
  }
```

### Reference

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)